T-SQL how to dynamically Pivot a tree
I've got a simple parent-child tree relationship that was built recursively



Parent
Child




A
B


B
E


B
C


E
NULL


C
NULL


A
F


F
NULL



this table comes from a recursive CTE:
with tree(parent, child) as (...)
select * from tree

I want to pivot it into



Parent
Child1
Child2




A
B
E


A
B
C


A
F




I've achieved this with a series of hardcoded joins, is something like this possible with somehow a dynamic pivot up to the Nth Child?
The current code is something like this:
with tree(parent, child) as (...)
select 
   P.parent, P.child as child1, C2.child as child2, C3.child as child3 
from tree as P
left join tree as C2
 on P.child = C2.parent
left join tree as C3
 on C2.child = C3.parent


Dynamic SQL would be the way to go. Been a while, but if I get a chance, I'll carve something up.

I thought about a dynamic join using the maximum depth but it would way too slow if it's deep, is it possible directly with Pivot?

"...is it possible directly with Pivot?" - No. You need to use dynamic SQL to generate the code for the pivot, or manually write the code yourself (which is almost never the answer). "I thought about a dynamic join using the maximum depth but it would way too slow if it's deep..." - It's not possible to comment on the performance without actually testing and measuring it. But I've had success in the past using dynamic SQL for dynamic pivoting.

-- Consider using nested sets. This gets a bit involved, but is 
-- crazy powerful. Tool up your table for nested sets with integer columns named
-- left and right. I abbreviate a bit so it's clear that references to them are
-- not in fact parts of join predicates.

DECLARE @tree table(
      id                    int PRIMARY KEY
    , parent_id             int 
    , node_name             varchar(50)
    -- add these columns to facilitate nested sets exercise
    , lvl                   int
    , lft                   int
    , rgt                   int
    , count_children        int
    , count_descendants     int
    , bread_crumb_trail     varchar(60) 
)

DECLARE @x table ( -- scratch table for nested set calcs
      id                    int PRIMARY KEY
    , parent_left           int
    , descendants           int
    , lft                   int
    , rgt                   int
    , ord                   int
)

DECLARE 
      @max_level            int
    , @row_id               int
    , @level                int
    , @count_rows           int
    , @last_parent_left     int
    , @fetchStatus          int = 0
    , @parent_left          int 
    , @lft                  int
    , @rgt                  int
    , @last_right           int
    , @count_descendants    int
    , @guilty_node_id       int

INSERT @tree (id, parent_id, node_name)
VALUES
      (1    , 9     , 'Volkswagen' )
    , (2    , 8     , 'Slartibartfast' )
    , (3    , 8     , 'Arthur Dent' )
    , (4    , 8     , 'Trillian' )
    , (5    , 9     , 'Subaru' )
    , (11   , 5     , 'Crosstrek' )
    , (50   , 11    , 'Base' )
    , (51   , 11    , 'Premium' )
    , (52   , 11    , 'Sport' )
    , (53   , 11    , 'Limited' )
    , (54   , 11    , 'Wilderness' )
    , (12   , 5     , 'Outback' )
    , (6    , 22    , 'African Savanna' )
    , (7    , 22    , 'African Forest' )
    , (500  , 22    , 'Asian' )
    , (8    , NULL  , 'Hitchhikers' )
    , (9    , NULL  , 'Cars')
    , (22   , NULL  , 'Elephants')


-- count children, mark level 0 (zero) 
UPDATE p
SET 
      -- nodes with NULL parent_id are level zero (0) [roots], movie stars
      lvl = CASE WHEN p.parent_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE NULL END 
    , count_children = ISNULL(cc.count_children, 0)
    , bread_crumb_trail = p.node_name
FROM @tree as p
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT parent_id, count(*) as count_children
    FROM @tree as c
    GROUP BY c.parent_id
) as cc
    ON p.id = cc.parent_id


-- mark descendant levels  
WHILE EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM @tree as c
    WHERE c.lvl IS NULL
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM @tree as p
        WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
    )
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE c
    SET 
          lvl = p.lvl + 1
        , bread_crumb_trail = p.bread_crumb_trail + ' -> ' + c.node_name
    FROM @tree as c
    INNER JOIN @tree as p 
        ON c.parent_id = p.id
    WHERE c.lvl IS NULL
    AND p.lvl IS NOT NULL
END


SELECT TOP 1 @max_level = lvl
FROM @tree ORDER BY lvl DESC;

SELECT @level = @max_level;

WHILE @level >= -1
BEGIN
    PRINT @level;

    UPDATE p
    SET 
          count_descendants = ISNULL(p.count_children, 0) + ISNULL(cc.count_descendants, 0)
    FROM @tree AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
              b.parent_id
            , SUM(count_descendants) AS count_descendants
        FROM @tree AS b  
        WHERE b.lvl = @level + 1
        GROUP BY b.parent_id
    ) AS cc
        ON p.id = cc.parent_id
    WHERE p.lvl = @level

    SELECT @count_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

    SELECT @level -= 1
END




SELECT @level = -1

WHILE @level <= @max_level
BEGIN
    SELECT @last_parent_left = -1, @fetchStatus = 0;

    DELETE @x;

    INSERT @x (
        id, parent_left, descendants, ord
    )
    SELECT 
            b.id
        , ISNULL(p.lft, 0) AS parent_left
        , b.count_descendants 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.lft ORDER BY b.node_name) as ord
    FROM @tree AS b  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @tree AS p  
        ON b.parent_id = p.id
        AND p.lvl = b.lvl - 1
    WHERE b.lvl = @level

    DECLARE curs_x CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id, parent_left, descendants 
    FROM @x
    ORDER BY parent_left, ord 
    FOR UPDATE OF lft, rgt 

    OPEN curs_x

    SELECT @fetchStatus = 0;

    WHILE @fetchStatus = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs_x
        INTO @row_id, @parent_left, @count_descendants 

        SELECT @fetchStatus = @@FETCH_STATUS;

        IF @fetchStatus = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @parent_left = @last_parent_left
            BEGIN
                SELECT 
                      @lft = @last_right + 1
                    , @rgt = @lft + @count_descendants * 2 + 1
                    , @last_right = @rgt
            END

            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT 
                      @last_parent_left = @parent_left
                    , @lft = @parent_left + 1
                    , @rgt = @lft + @count_descendants * 2 + 1
                    , @last_right = @rgt
            END

            UPDATE @x
            SET 
                  lft = @lft
                , rgt = @rgt
            WHERE id = @row_id
        END
    END

    CLOSE curs_x
    DEALLOCATE curs_x

    UPDATE h
    SET 
          lft = x.lft
        , rgt = x.rgt 
        , bread_crumb_trail = bread_crumb_trail
    FROM @tree as h
    INNER JOIN @x as x
        ON h.id = x.id

    SELECT @level += 1;
END

-- The @tree table is set up for reporting using nested sets. The maintenance of the left/right values 
-- isn't cheap. But if you're hierarchical dimension data isn't in rapid flux, it's worthwhile to use it 
-- and include a refresh of the nested set metadata as part of a maintenance procedure. Once the provisions 
-- are in, queries against it are powerful and fast.

-- Present contents of the entire hierarchical table as if it was a fully exploded tree
SELECT t.id, t.bread_crumb_trail, REPLICATE('|   ', t.lvl) + t.node_name as node_text
FROM @tree as t
ORDER BY lft

/*
-- result
id     bread_crumb_trail                                          node_text
------ -------------------------------------------- --------------------------
9      Cars                                         Cars
5      Cars -> Subaru                               |   Subaru
11     Cars -> Subaru -> Crosstrek                  |   |   Crosstrek
50     Cars -> Subaru -> Crosstrek -> Base          |   |   |   Base
53     Cars -> Subaru -> Crosstrek -> Limited       |   |   |   Limited
51     Cars -> Subaru -> Crosstrek -> Premium       |   |   |   Premium
52     Cars -> Subaru -> Crosstrek -> Sport         |   |   |   Sport
54     Cars -> Subaru -> Crosstrek -> Wilderness    |   |   |   Wilderness
12     Cars -> Subaru -> Outback                    |   |   Outback
1      Cars -> Volkswagen                           |   Volkswagen
22     Elephants                                    Elephants
7      Elephants -> African Forest                  |   African Forest
6      Elephants -> African Savanna                 |   African Savanna
500    Elephants -> Asian                           |   Asian
8      Hitchhiker                                   Hitchhiker
3      Hitchhiker -> Arthur Dent                    |   Arthur Dent
2      Hitchhiker -> Slartibartfast                 |   Slartibartfast
4      Hitchhiker -> Trillian                       |   Trillian

*/



-- descendants of a guilty node
SELECT @guilty_node_id = 11 -- Crosstrek

SELECT t.id, REPLICATE('|   ', t.lvl - gn.glvl) + t.node_name as node_text
FROM @tree as t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
          lft as glft
        , rgt as grgt
        , lvl as glvl
    FROM @tree as t
    WHERE t.id = @guilty_node_id
) as gn 
WHERE t.lft >= gn.glft  
AND t.rgt <= gn.grgt    
-- AND t.lvl > gn.glvl -- un-comment if you don't want root included
ORDER BY t.lft

/*
-- result
id          node_text
----------- -------------------
11          Crosstrek
50          |   Base
51          |   Premium
52          |   Sport
53          |   Limited
54          |   Wilderness

*/



-- ancestors of a guilty node
SELECT @guilty_node_id = 54 -- Wilderness

SELECT t.id, REPLICATE('|   ', t.lvl) + t.node_name as node_text
FROM @tree as t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
          lft as glft
        , rgt as grgt
        , lvl as glvl
    FROM @tree as t
    WHERE t.id = @guilty_node_id
) as gn 
WHERE t.lft <= gn.glft  
AND t.rgt >= gn.grgt    
-- AND t.lvl > gn.glvl -- un-comment if you don't want root included
ORDER BY t.lft DESC

/*
-- result
id          node_text
----------- ---------------------------------
9           Cars
5           |   Subaru
11          |   |   Crosstrek
54          |   |   |   Wilderness

*/




